# How to access a WebApp hosted in localhost:3000 from a WebApp hosted in localhost:5000?

Tags: node.js

I have a NodeJS webapp hosted in **localhost:5000** and another Flask webapp hosted in **localhost:3000**.
From a route in the NodeJS app I want to access an html file hosted in localhost:3000.

How do I do that?

**NodeJS app route**:

```
router.get('/fetchpredict', (req, res) => {
  //In this route I want to fetch the HTML page hosted in localhost:3000
})
```

**Note: I don't want the data in JSON format. I want the the HTML page rendered as it is in localhost:3000**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use something like `node-fetch` in order to send the request to `localhost:3000` from *inside* your `/fetchpredict` route... You'll also need to make the route handler async.

Something like:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
// ...
router.get('/fetchpredict', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const resp = await fetch("localhost:3000");
    const html = await resp.text();
    res.status(200).send(html);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried `node-fetch` as well as `axios` but I don't want the data in `json` format. I want it as an HTML page itself.

Comment: So then you'd just do the fetch part and use `text()` instead of `json()`...See updated answer. Keep in mind if you want to render that HTML client side, you may have to do that via client side javascript. Just because you are sending html/text data back does not mean the client will automatically render it.

Comment: You could also just redirect them to the other page, which I don't recommend doing.. but it would work (it would render the html w/o you having to do anything if you redirected).